# Git overwrote local with remote when reverting a push

Tags: windows-10, git, data-recovery, github, github-desktop

Using github desktop I committed and tried to push local code to master. I hadn't been updating the remote repo much so my local version had about 2 months worth of work. I made the commit and tried to push with git lfs (some files were quite big). Github desktop didn't seem to be responding so I closed it.

I immediately opened it again and saw that the commit was still there waiting to be pushed. I decided I did not want to push it anymore so I clicked revert commit. Now my local repo has been replaced by the remote and I don't know how to retrieve my lost work. I have no idea what to do. Using windows file recovery has not worked.

I'm seriously screwed If I can't retrieve this work. Any advice is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Well its been 10 months ago so by now you either have recovered the work or done it again.
but to answer the question is this.

what happened here was when you canceled it,  for some reason it discarded your changes. it was not supposed to do that, but it did.

now it is set to send everything it discarded to the recycle bin, and you should have been able to recover it from there right after this happened

but as its 10 months ago i doubt its still there or that you even still need it